# JavaScript Time Output not matching REST value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a date/time value in REST as follows. This is the required format by SharePoint for storing date/time:

```
"EventDate": "2015-04-20T12:00:00Z",
```

When I try to output this using Angular, it is showing the time as 4 hours off (earlier):

```
Start Date: {{item.startDate | date: 'M/d/yy h:mm a'}}
```

Displays as:

```
4/20/15 8:00 AM
```

I need it to show the date/time as it is stored in REST (ex. if 12:00 in REST, I want it to output 12:00 PM)

If I do a straight output of rest, it will display:

```
2015-04-20T12:00:00Z
```

But formatting it as above turns it into:

```
4/20/15 8:00 AM
```

Instead of:

```
4/20/15 12:00 PM
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `UTC` filter as well

```
  {{"2015-04-20T12:00:00Z" | date: 'M/d/yy hh:mm a' : 'UTC'}}

  // 4/20/15 12:00 PM
```

As per the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date#), the third parameter is `timezone` which can be either UTC/GMT

```
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
```

Comment: Works. I didn't see that in the documentation explicitly: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date#! I am guessing it is implicit as stated here " It understands UTC/GMT". Wish the docs had a few more examples.

Comment: Yes, examples were missing.But they've specified the format `$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)` So the second parameter is `timezone`